# How to move a specific branch of a repo to a mono repo in a folder?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have repo1 with X branch. At the end of it I want X in a folder in repo2 WITH history, I should not only be able to see the commit history, I should also be able to access the file history.

I tried a lot out of the internet, but it usually didn't work, and those which did, didn't get the file history, only the commit history, so then git blame wouldn't work.

- Repo1 - branch-all folders
- Repo2 - other folders
- Required - repo1 doesn't matter
- .          Repo2 - repo1_folder - all folders

Because I have to change the path, it's not keeping the history (GitHub will not detect it as the same file)

Comment: `git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter` or the corresponding `git filter-repo` invocation? Please show (or link) us what you have tried and explain why it hasn't worked. It also helps to show a concrete file listing of your repos directories instead of explaining it in abstract terms.

Comment: There is no file history. There are only commits, and the commits are the history.

Comment: If you got to a specific file on Github and click history, it shows file history i.e. which commits it has been part of. I found a lot of methods on the internet, but none achieved this.

Comment: Git (and GitHub) can *fake up* a "file history" by reading commit history, one commit (or commit-pair really) at a time, and *comparing the contents of each commit*. If the two commits don't touch the file(s) you care about, Git skips over that commit and moves on (backwards) to the previous commit. Repeat, omitting commits from pairs that have the *same version* of that file, and you've filtered the commit history down to a faked file history. But there is no file history: there are just the commits.

Comment: What this means is that you either have all the commits, and hence all the history, or you don't have all the commits and are missing the corresponding history. You can, if you like, take *all* the commits and use those to make an all-new history (all new set of commits) in which only the files you care about *exist*, but this is an all-new history: it doesn't join up with previous history. So when someone adds *more* commits to the original repository, you'll now need to repeat that process.

Comment: Added the file thing